# searching file in IntellijIDea does contain Str1 and does not contain Str2

Tags: intellij-idea, search

i am new to Intellij Idea and i like to use two features :

- Find in Files features (CTL + H)
- Find by class name (CTL + SHIFT + T)

but with this constraint :
the result must contain str1 and does not contain str2

I tried regular expressions but it seems to be a little complex to do it ?
is there a easy way to do that ?

Comment: I think you should use regular expressions, because they are fast and do not require additional plugins. Could you explain, please, Str1 and Str2?